# Bot emulator says couldn't send retry

Tags: c#, botframework

I am new to Microsoft Bot Framework.
I created my first bot application by using bot application template on Visual Studio 2015. it is running fine and below is the message I get when i run this.

Describe your bot here and your terms of use etc.

Visit Bot Framework to register your bot. When you register it, remember to set your bot's endpoint to

https://your_bots_hostname/api/messages.

And I have downloaded botframework-emulator 3.5.29 and installed. On the emulator i have entered http://localhost:3979/api/messages/ and left the App Id & App Password fields as empty. everything was looks fine. But when i type any message on the emulator I am getting Couldn't send retry notification on emulator.

Please can anyone help me on this.

Thanks,

Comment: what endpoint did you put on the settings page of dev.botframework.com for your bot?  If you just want to test locally leave the endpoint blank.  if you use ngrok use the ngrok https endpoint.

Comment: I am running it on my local system.

Comment: @ people downvoting: it could be great if you could motivate that. This seems to me an honest question. If you feel there's something to improve, please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [download ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

In the log click on `Edit ngrok settings` and select the file ngrok.exe

[image: bot log]

When are you finish try connect to this url `http://localhost:3979/api/messages`

Comment: I am getting this error after selecting ngrok.exe                           [13:46:06] Failed to start ngrok: undefined 
[13:46:06] ngrok may already be running in a different process. ngrok's free tier allows only one instance at a time per host.

Comment: Are you downloading the version indicated for your operating system? If is the correct try download the file again

Comment: Also i am running my bot and emulator on the my local (same machine). Do we really want to configure ngrok for local

Comment: In App Settings from Bot Frameworck Channel Emulator check the  "Bypass ngrok for local addresses"

Comment: After checking that Bypass option also getting same issue.  Do i need to do something else ?

Comment: In the controller, delete BotAuthentication decoration and try again

Comment: Do we need to use only VS 2017 ? I am using VS 2015. is that the problem

Comment: Hi Sergio Reguera, Thanks for your response. I found the solution.  the problem is not from the bot application, As i mentioned firewall is enabled on my machine and I did run the emulator with user access.  when I run the emulator with admin  access it prompt me to provide access and I clicked yes, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Run Bot Framework Emulator as administrator.

Find the program icon in your start menu, right click, then "More", then "Run as Administrator".